# Image not printing when using office.interop printout method

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, image

I have a document with a image in the footer and an image in the main body.

My problem is the footer prints fine but the image in the main body doesnt. If I print from the document natively in Word it all prints OK but when i use

```
MsWord.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(Background:=False, Range:=Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument, Item:=Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent, PageType:=Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages)ied adding it as a watermark and that prints
```

It doesnt print the pic in the body.

Is there anything your aware of that would stop this.

FYI I tried adding it as a watermark and that worked, its just when its in the main body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by making it the watermark with lots of white space